# Google Slides tutorial code does not apply desired filename to a copied file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I am following Google's ["Data Merge"](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/merge) tutorial to import data from Google Sheets into Google Slides, and the part that does not work fully is ["Copying an existing presentation."](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/presentations#copying_an_existing_presentation) When I run the provided Apps Script code, I am getting a copy of the file with the name "Copy of ..." instead of "New presentation title".

```
// Duplicate the template presentation using the Drive API.
var copyTitle = 'New presentation title';
var requests = {
  name: copyTitle
};
var driveResponse = Drive.Files.copy({
  resource: requests
}, originalpresentationID);
var presentationCopyId = driveResponse.id;
Logger.log(driveResponse.title) # Logger returns: "Copy of ..."
```

How can I properly create a copy of an existing file, with my desired name? It seems the tutorial is wrong.

Comment: Drive v2, not v3. `{title: "new name"}`

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this and faced the same issue. Looks like a bug.
As a way around try renaming your copy file after is has been created. Here's the code.

```
var copyTitle = 'New presentation title';
    var driveResponse = Drive.Files.copy({          
    }, originalpresentationID);
    var presentationCopyId = driveResponse.id;
    var copyPPT = DriveApp.getFileById(presentationCopyId);
    copyPPT.setName(copyTitle);
```

Comment: Drive in Apps Script is v2, which uses `title` as the filename property. V3 uses `name`.

Comment: @tehhowch :I've tried with `title` as well. Still it is creating a file with name as 'Copy of...' instead of provided title.

Comment: You must have also used the incorrect metadata specification - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code used in that example mixes in some syntax from other languages and client libraries.

The `Drive` "advanced service" in Google Apps Script uses v2 of the Drive REST API, for which there are some property name differences. Notably, the filename is `title`, not `name`.

Additionally, the syntax for a `drive#file` resource (aka metadata) in the [`Drive.Files.copy`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy) request is not as a child `resource` property of the parameter, but as the parameter directly:

```
const metadata = {
  title: "new name",
  // other properties
};
const options = {
  // optional request parameters
  // fields: "*",
};
var newFileMetaData = Drive.Files.copy(metadata, sourceId, options);
```